# PL SQL Exception value replace valid result

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following trigger created:

```
create or replace TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER
BEFORE UPDATE OF PRODUCT_ID ON MY_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
V_COUNT NUMBER;

PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

BEGIN 
SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT_NAME
INTO :NEW.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM ALL_PRODUCTS_TABLE
WHERE PRODUCT_ID = :NEW.PRODUCT_ID;

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN no_data_found THEN 
    :NEW.PRODUCT_NAME := 'Not found';

END;
```

The code runs correctly when updating if the exception is removed (except when, there's no value, evidently). However, if I add the exception and test the trigger by using an existing/valid Product ID, it will return 'Not Found' regardless of what product id was used.
Not sure why or what am I missing.

Thanks

Comment: Why is that trigger autonomous transaction?

Comment: I'm using it to avoid 'table mutation' issues

Comment: Nothing is mutating here. Trigger is based on MY_TABLE and you're selecting from ALL_PRODUCTS_TABLE.

Comment: my bad, found the error. Apologies for that. Thanks